# Find grandparent node with Python and lxml using xpath()

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

Is there a method to get a parent node with .xpath for item of type Element()?

I has HTML like this:

```
<table> ...
   <tr><td>...</td></tr>
   <tr><td><h3 class="product_name">Product</h3></td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to get a table element, where table is the first parent element for h3 of table 'table'.

from lxml.html import fromstring

```
html = fromstring
for h3 in html.xpath('//h3[@class="product_name"]'):
  parent_table = h3.xpath('???')
```

What xpath should I use?

Comment: Did you try `'../../'` ?

Comment: @DainDwarf That is invalid xpath.  Also, `../..` will get the _tr_ element containing the _h3_.  Additionally, any xpath that does not use the ancestor axis will be tied to the exact structure of the document.

Answer (score 3):

`./ancestor::table[1]`

This will get the `table` element that is the closest (grand)parent/ancestor relative to the context node.